# Containers are getting stuck behind the app header (Android)

Tags: android, xml

I've been trying to create an app that would allow a user to enter timetable information but i'm getting stuck at the design part, the first "Edit Text" container is getting stuck behind the title header of the app and i'm not sure why. I'd like to make it so it's forced below the header (and the other containers are force below the one above it, like a stack)

[Image showing problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oaybh.png)

There is another container above the "Day of Week", you can just see the bottom part of it sticking out below the header. Here is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:weightSum="1">
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ModuleCode"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/module_code"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:gravity="fill"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_weight="0.14"
     />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/DayOfWeek"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/day_of_week"
    android:inputType="text" />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/StartTime"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/start_time"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:inputType="text" />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/Duration"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/duration"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:inputType="text" />

<EditText
android:id="@+id/SessionType"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/type_of_session"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:inputType="text" />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/Room"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/room"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:inputType="text" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/myListView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1.07" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same problem, i just added a margin-top to the LinearLayout so it clears the header. for example:

note here i use a percentRelativeLayout, but this works with all layouts.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
           xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:background="@drawable/background"
           android:layout_marginTop="55dp"<--- this one!
           android:padding="10dp">
```

Comment: @Patterrz if my awnser helped, plz flag it as the correct awnser, thx!

Answer (score 0):

it is because the action bar is added externally on top of the view

you could either remove the action bar and add it to your xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="#298859"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
```

or simply as add a margin top to your first item

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/ModuleCode"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/module_code"
android:inputType="text"
android:layout_marginTop="30dp"/>
```